# PayPal PHP SDK - Tax for an item

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm currently building a PHP script to handle payments for a product and want to add VAT to the product however it doesn't seem to be be affecting the price or showing up on PayPal when you go to pay.

I'm unsure if this is even supported on products however the function seems to be there to set it so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Would I have to set the tax as a separate product?

My code is below.

```
use PayPal\Api\Amount;
use PayPal\Api\Item;
use PayPal\Api\ItemList;
use PayPal\Api\Payer;
use PayPal\Api\Payment;
use PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls;
use PayPal\Api\Transaction;

$invoiceID = uniqid('TEST-');

$payer = new Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod("paypal");

$item1 = new Item();
$item1->setName('Team Members')
  ->setTax(23)
  ->setCurrency('GBP')
  ->setQuantity(3)
  ->setPrice(115);

$itemList = new ItemList();
$itemList->setItems(array($item1));

$amount = new Amount();
$amount->setCurrency("GBP")
  ->setTotal(345);

$transaction = new Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)
  ->setItemList($itemList)
  ->setDescription("Registration")
  ->setInvoiceNumber($invoiceID);

$baseUrl = 'http://testingdomain.com';
$redirectUrls = new RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("$baseUrl/ppa.php?success=true")
  ->setCancelUrl("$baseUrl/ppa.php?success=false");

$payment = new Payment();
$payment->setIntent("sale")
  ->setPayer($payer)
  ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls)
  ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
try {
  $payment->create($apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  print_r($ex);
  exit(1);
}
echo $payment->getApprovalLink()."\n";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated with this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add `Details` object too with these information.

Please have a look at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/payments/CreatePaymentUsingPayPal.php#L44-L60 for more information.